# C++11 Multithreading Data Protection Semantics

Tags: multithreading, c++11

In the following code:

```
class SomeClass  
{  
private:  
    static SomeType sharedvar;  
    static std::mutex Mutex;  
public:   
    void DoStuff()  
    {  
        Mutex.lock();  
        //do stuff with sharedvar  
        Mutex.unlock();  
    }  
}
```

is it guaranteed that the changes to sharedvar will actually be stored when Mutex.unlock() is called, and not simply kept in the CPU's cache? I read about a similar example with a global variable, and it explained that this behavior occurs because the compiler can't know if a function implemented in an external library accesses the global variable, so the variable has to be kept up to date before each call to that function. However, in this example, sharedvar is private and can only be accessed by functions declared in SomeClass, which the compiler can see and make assumptions about. If sharedvar is updated when Mutex.unlock() is called, how/why does this this behavior occur (please explain in detail)? If it isn't, what can I do to fix it (would I need volatile)? I also had the crazy idea of declaring std::mutex::lock as a friend function, in order to reintroduce the uncertainty that (I think) makes the example above work.

Comment: In most cases you should not lock the mutex directly, instead use a scoped lock like e.g. [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: this is a good question. It depends on the hardware, the OS and the compiler. I.e. The same question could also consider instructions reordering performed by compilers, etc. By experience, I have never seen a problem resulting from delayed sharedvar writing. But this is not a proof.

Comment: @chmike I'm working an a project with two static private class members: one that points to a dynamically allocated array, and an integer that holds the length of the array. I'm afraid that one might be written to before the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is guaranteed.

I wanted to quote the standard but i don't have it now, so I'm quoting cppreference.com. It says about the memory order of the operations

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock

> Prior unlock() operation on the same mutex **synchronizes-with** (as defined in std::memory_order) this operation.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock

> This operation **synchronizes-with** (as defined in std::memory_order) any subsequent lock operation that obtains ownership of the same mutex.

---

It won't be synchronized properly if the mutex is not `static` and there are more than one instance. The memory order of the `lock` and `unlock` only applies to the same mutex.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to make the mutex static, I fixed the code.